# In angular template I get: property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular

When I try to made custom formControl component and use this [tutorial](https://ritchiejacobs.be/angular-custom-form-component) in template

```js
<input
    class="field"
    (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
/>
```

I get following compilation error

> error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

This bug is easy to fix if it occurs in .ts files but **how to fix it on .html template?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```js
<input 
    #fieldInput 
    class="field"
    (input)="onChange(fieldInput.value)" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spend some time to find solution and finally I have luck and found it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35293) - use `$any`

```js
<input
    class="field"
    (input)="onChange($any($event.target).value)"
/>
```

Comment: `<input #fieldInput type="text" name="field" (input)="onChange(fieldInput .value)" />` I think there may be a better solution

Comment: @OnurÖzkır yep - looks good - add your comment as answer